# ObjectMapper Redis Serialization Issue

Tags: java, redis, jackson

I am trying to cache An entity like this:

```
class Foo {
    String attr1;
    Set<Long> attr2;
    Set<Long> attr3;
}
```

My ObjectMapper + Serializer Configuration:

```
  @Bean
  public RedisSerializer<Object> serializer() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.activateDefaultTyping(mapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator());
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.addMixIn(Collection.class, HibernateCollectionMixIn.class);
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(mapper);
  }
```

With this configuration, my entity is stored in Redis like this:

```
{
  "attr1": "123456789",
  "attr2": [
    "java.util.HashSet",
    [
      [
        "java.lang.Long",
        1
      ],
      [
        "java.lang.Long",
        2
      ],
      [
        "java.lang.Long",
        3
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "attr3": [
    "java.util.HashSet",
    []
  ]
}
```

But when trying to read back from redis, my code fails with following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.lang.Object
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"attr1":"123456789","attr2":["java.util.HashSet",[["java.lang.Long",1],["java.lang.Long",2],["java.lang.Long",3]]],"attr3":["java.util.HashSet",[]]}"; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.lang.Object
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"attr1":"123456789","attr2":["java.util.HashSet",[["java.lang.Long",1],["java.lang.Long",2],["java.lang.Long",3]]],"attr3":["java.util.HashSet",[]]}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.read(RedisSerializationContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.deserializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:571)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:536)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:402)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
```

If I remove default typing from ObjectMapper, exception changes to :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.foo.Foo
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.findByAuuid(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.FooService.getFoo(FooServiceImpl.java:80)
    at com.foo.FooService.getFooImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$349e7f48.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

What should I do so that I can de serialize this without problems.

TIA